# use perlbrew with dist zilla test

Tags: perl, perlbrew, dist-zilla

I am using the [Dist::Zilla](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla) module to release and test my module. I am also using [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/). When I run a script using perlbrew that includes my module, the script runs fine:

```
use strict;
use My::Module;
```

However, whenever I run `dzil test`, on a test that just tries to include my module:

```
#!perl -T
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Test::More;

plan tests => 1;

BEGIN {
    use_ok( 'My::Module' ) || print "Bail out!\n";
}

diag( "Testing My::Module $My::Module::VERSION, Perl $], $^X" );
```

It fails with this error saying that it can't find the module Mouse (which my module includes):

```
Error:  Can't locate Mouse.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Mouse module) (@INC contains:
/Users/user/github/My/Module/.build/HoKOnIQGYr/blib/lib
/Users/user/github/My/Module/.build/HoKOnIQGYr/blib/arch
/Users/user/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Users/user/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Users/user/perl5/lib/perl5
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/
/Users/user/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Users/user/perl5/lib/perl5
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/
/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18
/Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Network/Library/Perl/5.18
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2
/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/5.18
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18) at
/Users/user/github/My/Module/.build/HoKOnIQGYr/blib/lib/My/Module.pm line 4.
```

It says that it cannot find Mouse.pm, which I know is located at

```
/Users/user/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-2level
```

I see that for some reason that directory is not located in `@INC`, which is interesting because if I run this command to print out all the directories in `@INC`:

```
perl -e 'print "$_\n" for @INC'
```

I get:

```
/Users/user/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-2level
/Users/user/perl5/lib/perl5
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/
/Users/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/site_perl/5.16.0/darwin-2level
/Users/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/site_perl/5.16.0
/Users/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/5.16.0/darwin-2level
/Users/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/5.16.0
.
```

So when I run perl on the command line then the `darwin-2level` directory is present in `@INC`, but whenever I run `dzil test` it is not. This might not have much to do with `Dist::Zilla`, since I think `Dist::Zilla` just creates `Makefile.PL` and runs `make test` for you. Could this be because for testing an older version of perl is being required? Like so:

```
use 5.006;
```

But even so, some Perlbrew directories are present in `@INC` during the test such as

```
/Users/user/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

Does anyone know how I can make it so I can use the Mouse installation in my perl directory instead of installing a systemwide one? I had a previous error with another module that couldn't be found when I ran `dzil test`, and that module was in the same directory as `Mouse`. I was able to fix the issue by installing the module systemwide instead of locally in my home `perl5` directory, but I'd prefer to use the Mouse installed by Perlbrew and not mess with my system perl if possible. I am using Perlbrew version 0.73.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to install it using the wrong `perl` since you're using `dzil` installed by a different `perl` than the one you want to use.

Furthermore, you shouldn't see any of the following in your `perlbrew`ed `perl`'s `@INC`:

- `/Users/user/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-2level`
- `/Users/user/perl5/lib/perl5`
- `/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.16.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/` (You `perlbrew`ed `perl` isn't even threaded!!!)

---

1. Let's clean up your environment.

   1. Unset env vars `PERL5LIB`, `PERLLIB`, `PERL5OPT`, `PERL_MM_OPT` and `PERL_MB_OPT`. Permanently. Get rid of them in your login scripts, then unset them from the current shell or log back in. (Make a note of what they were as a backup.)
   2. Clear `cpan'`s configuration item `makepl_arg`. From within `cpan`,

      ```
      o conf makepl_arg      # Just to see its current value as a backup.
      o conf makepl_arg ''
      o conf commit
      ```

      In particular, we want to remove anything that indicates an installation path, including `INSTALL_BASE`, `PREFIX` and `LIB`.
   3. Clear `cpan'`s configuration item `mbuildpl_arg`. From within `cpan`,

      ```
      o conf mbuildpl_arg    # Just to see its current value as a backup.
      o conf mbuildpl_arg ''
      o conf commit
      ```

      In particular, we want to remove anything that indicates an installation path, including `--install_base`, `--prefix` and `--lib`.
   4. Since you're there, do the following from within `cpan`:

      ```
      o conf build_dir_reuse 0
      o conf commit
      ```

      This will restore the setting to its default, which will save you headaches if it was changed.
2. Install the dependencies.

   ```
   cpan Dist::Zilla Mouse
   ```

---

At this point, executing `which dzil` should give

```
/Users/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin/dzil
```

If so, you should be good to go.

If not, do `hash -r` and try `which dzil` again. (This shouldn't be needed, but just to be sure.)

If still not, provide the output of the following commands:

```
echo "$PATH"
which cpan
head -n 3 "$( which cpan )"
echo 'o conf' | cpan | grep arg
which dzil
head -n 3 "$( which dzil )"
perl -V                           # Uppercase "V"
```

Comment: Thanks! So it works now. I hope you don't mind if I ask a few questions about your solution. This link (http://perlbrew.pl/Perlbrew-and-Friends.html) discusses installing all modules under `~/perl5/perlbrew/bin` with cpanm so that when you switch perls you don't have to reinstall modules. That's what I did previously. Is that not the preferred solution? Should I instead be installing modules for each individual perl like you had me do? Also, how did you know dzil was installed for a different perl? Because of the error? Or because of what was included in `@INC`?

Comment: And are all perlbrew installations not threaded, or just the one I have installed?

Comment: @srchulo, There are some you would have to install anyway (e.g. Mouse) because they have architecture- or version-dependent elements. You're better off reinstalling them all because of issues with dependencies on such modules by modules that aren't arch- or version-dependent.

Comment: @srchulo, You can build a threaded Perl by specifying `-Dusethreads` or the friendlier, perlbrew-specific alias `--thread`.